# How can resolve this syntax error in FROM clause?

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection bes = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\JAMES DEAN\Documents\aha.mdb;User Id=admin; Password=;;");
System.Data.DataTable pc = new System.Data.DataTable();

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter save = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Info (Quantity, Unit, Account, Description , Amount, Total Amount, [Date]) VALUES '"+ textBox1.Text +"','" +textBox2.Text +
            "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5 + "','" + textBox6.Text+ "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" ,bes);
save.Fill(pc);
dataGridView1.DataSource = pc;
```

thanks :D

---

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand save = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(
    "Insert into Info (Quantity, Unit, Account, Description , Amount, Total Amount, Account Title, [Date]) VALUES '"
    + textBox1.Text +"','" 
    +textBox2.Text +"','" 
    + textBox3.Text + "','" 
    + textBox4.Text + "','" 
    + textBox5 + "','" 
    + textBox6.Text+ "','"
    + comboBox1.Text+"','" 
    + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" ,bes);
save.ExecuteNonQuery();
bes.Close();
```

this is now my code and i still get error TT

Comment: Oh god.. Please **PLEASE** always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: And `SELECT` doesn't have a syntax with `VALUES`. What have you try to do exactly? Do you wanna use `WHERE` instead to filter your data with these values? You should always use your queries in your db manager first. And use `using` statement to dispose your database connections and adapters.

Comment: is this a unholy merge of a select and a insert statement?

Comment: Please study [basic sql syntax first](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp), yours is totally invalid.

Comment: sorry i dont know what you mean :( im just copying this from youtube, and i am just newbie in coding (( i just want this to run :D for my thesis :)

Comment: try something more in the lines of: select list, of, columns from tablename where any_filtering_goes_here

Comment: Use the Query editor from MS Access, then switch to SQL View to get a basic view of what a valid SQL Statement looks like. **Then** you can read up on parametrized and try to make your own, correct query.

Comment: i just want to filter the data from my access database and ive changed the vaues to where and the error is still :(

Comment: thank thank you guys :D

Comment: If you're doing this for your **thesis** then you need to learn this stuff. Don't wing it from youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two queries `Select` and `Insert`

**Select**

```
SELECT Quantity, Unit, Account, Description , Amount, Total Amount, [Date] FROM Info
```

**Insert**

```
Insert into Info (Quantity, Unit, Account, Description , Amount, Total Amount, [Date]) VALUES ...
```

Also
1. Column cannot have space in between.
2. Please use parameterized query to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: Nitpick.  Columns can have a space, they would just have to be bracketed.